# R function slda.em: error when setting the logistic = T argument

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I am trying to run supervised LDA on a set of annotated tweets. I keep getting this error msg:

> Error in structure(.Call("collapsedGibbsSampler", documents, as.integer(K),  : This should not have happened (nan).

How do I fix it?
It only happens when I set `logistic = T`.

Code below. `s` is a sample of the data.

```
corpus1 <- lexicalize(tweets[s], lower=TRUE)    
to.keep <- corpus1$vocab[word.counts(corpus1$documents, corpus1$vocab) >= 1]
documents <- lexicalize(tweets[s], lower=TRUE, vocab=to.keep)
params <- sample(c(-1, 1), num.topics, replace=TRUE)

result <- slda.em(documents=documents,
                      K=num.topics,
                      vocab=to.keep,
                      num.e.iterations=10,
                      num.m.iterations=4,
                      alpha=1.0, eta=0.1,
                      annotations = as.integer(annotations[s]),
                      params,
                      variance=0.25,
                      lambda=1.0,
                      logistic=T)
```

Comment: Does it also happen when you pass `logistic=TRUE`? You may have overwritten `T` in your environment.

Comment: Also, please update this question to include a reproducible example. Right now you don't show any of the packages you include and we also don't have `tweets`.